# How to manual wake a perl sleep function?

Tags: perl, sleep, manual

I was wondering if it was possible to manually wake a perl script that has gone to sleep.
Basically I set my script to sleep for say an hour after performing something, and 10 minutes later I realize I want it to run again.

The platform I'm running on is linux, with a tcsh shell.

Again, Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On many systems, system calls like `sleep` can be interrupted with signals. On such an interruption, `sleep` will return the number of seconds that it actually slept for and set `$!`. Of course you have to use a signal that will allow your script to continue. If you haven't set any specific signal handler, a combination of `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` will do the trick, too.

Example:

```
$ perl -e 'print "slept for ", sleep 1000, " seconds.\n";' &
[2] 6220
$ kill -STOP 6220
$ kill -CONT 6220
slept for 8 seconds[2]+  Stopped     perl -e ...
```

Another example (trivial `SIGUSR1` handler):

```
$ perl -e '$SIG{USR1}=sub{}; print "slept for ", sleep 1000, "s.\n"' &
[1] 2419
$ kill -USR1 2419
slept for 4s
```

Comment: What perl, what OS and what shell?  Can you reproduce without another job in the background?  (I see that your backgrounded perl is actually job no. 2 in your shell.)  I cannot reproduce under v5.16, Linux 2.6 and bash — the sleep is unaffected by being STOPped and CONTinued, terminating after the appropriate number of seconds.  Ancient Linux [appeared to mishandle SIGCONT](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/nanosleep_linux/SIGCONT), and perl's "restartable syscall" semantics usually make interrupting a sleep non-trivial anyway.

Comment: That test was with Cygwin, any version and any number of background jobs already running. I couldn't get my first example to work in Linux either, so I've added a second example that does work.

Comment: Thanks!! I was able to reproduce the manual waking on a Linus terminal.